# Windows 10 Universal Voice Commands Command Prefix

Tags: unity-game-engine, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, voice-recognition, cortana

Hello I have a question regarding using Voice Commands in a Windows 10 UA. I have added a Voice Command Definition file into a Unity3D created Universal app and added the necessary code to install it at first run. However, when having started the first time, it never responds to voice commands. I added a Command Prefix, which should allow someone to start the app by uttering that prefix, but when I do that it just opens Cortana search.

I am at a loss as to why that happens.

Below are the important pieces of the code:

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.2">

  <CommandSet xml:lang="en-gb">
    <CommandPrefix>Unity Battle</CommandPrefix>
    <Example>Speak to the game</Example>

    <Command Name="startWithText">
      <Example>Say the message you want to appear in the game</Example>
      <ListenFor> {naturalLanguage} </ListenFor>
      <Feedback> Starting Game... </Feedback>
      <Navigate/>
    </Command>

  <PhraseTopic Label="naturalLanguage" Scenario="Natural Language"/>

  </CommandSet>

</VoiceCommands>
```

install code:

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            try
            {
                Windows.Storage.StorageFile vcdStorageFile =
                    await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"VoiceCommandDefinition.xml");

                await
                    Windows.ApplicationModel.VoiceCommands.VoiceCommandDefinitionManager
                        .InstallCommandDefinitionsFromStorageFileAsync(vcdStorageFile);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Installing Voice Commands Failed: " + ex.ToString());
            }
}
```

On Activated:

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            string appArgs = "";

            switch (args.Kind)
            {
                case ActivationKind.Protocol:
                    ProtocolActivatedEventArgs eventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
                    splashScreen = eventArgs.SplashScreen;
                    appArgs += string.Format("Uri={0}", eventArgs.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
                    break;
                case ActivationKind.VoiceCommand:
                    SpeechHelper.HandleSpeechCommand(args);
                    break;
            }
            InitializeUnity(appArgs);
        }
```

I have already ran through the code with the debugger attached but it never hits the OnActivated(..) method.

Comment: The integration with Cortana means you need to invoke Cortana UI first and then run your commands from there. And you can ask inside cortana which commands to run as described in details in [post](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2014/10/20/Integrating-Cortana-in-your-Universal-Windows-Phone-app.aspx).  Is that the step you want to buypass, i.e. run commands without Cortana UI?

Comment: Have you tried text  input "Unity Battle" in Cortana ?